# SSIS 2014 Log provider for sql server from Connection Manager

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created connection Manger to Project level which points to Logging database. I want to use same connection for logging in all packages in a project but when I try to set up logging for individual package I don't see this connection manager in existing list. When I click new in configuration of log provider I always get an error saying specified provider is not supported. In connection manager (Project level) I have used .netProviders\SqlClientData provider.

Answer (score 0):

The Project Deployment Model, new in the 2012 release of SSIS allows for Project level connection managers. The intention is that developers will want to use the new, native logging provided in the SSISDB catalog along with the built-in reports. The *very* nice thing about this approach is that you the developer don't need to do anything to turn it on. It's on by default and once deployed, if you want to change your logging level from the default to Verbose, it's a change in the invocation of the package instead of *editing* the package.

If you want to use the "old" way of logging and configuration, you will need to right click on your project and select "Convert to package deployment model".

Comment: I understand this but when I choose a provider I don't get ado.net provider for sql server in data provider list